# update one column value with multiple columns mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-update

hi i have a table in my database .

```
ShopID | ParentID | SELL 

1          0        2,3
2          1        1,2,3
3          1        2,3,4
4          0        5,6
5          4        5,6,7
6          4        6,7,8
```

i want to add the children  `SELL` values to the parent shop's `SELL` values , but don't want to add duplicate values ,

finally i want to have a table like this

```
ShopID | ParentID | SELL 

1          0        1,2,3,4
2          1        1,3
3          1        2,4
4          0        5,6,7,8
5          4        5,7
6          4        6,8
```

is this possible with `MySQL` , please help . thanks in advance .

Comment: Please don't do that. Don't store more than 1 value ina column. This violates the 1st normalisation form of DB design.

Comment: @juergend , but for now i can not do the change you are suggesting , do you have an answer to my quesion . please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT s1.shopid, s1.parentid, IFNULL( s2.sales, s1.SELL ) SELL
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT parentid, GROUP_CONCAT( sell ) sales
  FROM shop
  GROUP BY parentid
)s2 ON s1.ShopId = s2.parentid;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/780b0/8)

Update Query:

```
 update shop
    SET SELL=s.SELL 
    from shop join (select s1.shopid,s1.parentid,ifnull(s2.sales,s1.SELL) SELL from shop s1 left join 
    (select parentid,group_concat(sell) sales from shop
    group by parentid) s2
    on s1.ShopId=s2.parentid) s
    on shop.shopid = s.shopid
```

Comment: hi your solutions works , but the parent column now contains duplicate values .  how can i remove them , and also i need a update query

Comment: some times i get values like 2,3,4,5,5,5,4 , i need to get only 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: can you give sample data for this case

Comment: This is a problem with your table structure.This cant be handled through sql queries.So in that case you have to modify your table structure and store the values saperately.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a new column.

Like :

```
ShopID | ParentID | SELL | Total Sell
```

But the best is to store one value per record like :

```
ShopID | ParentID | SELL 

1          0        2
1          0        3
```

Than you would be able to manipulate easily the data...

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sellforce` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ShopID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ParentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Sell` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

INSERT INTO `sellforce` (`ShopID`, `ParentID`, `Sell`) VALUES
( 1, 0, 2),
( 2, 1, 1),
( 1, 0, 3),
( 2, 1, 3);

CREATE VIEW `sellforce1` AS select `sellforce`.`ShopID` AS `ShopID`,`sellforce`.`ParentID` AS `ParentID`,group_concat(distinct `sellforce`.`Sell` separator ',') AS `GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ``Sell`` )` from `sellforce` group by `sellforce`.`ShopID`;
```

Comment: hi , this is an insert query , can you please help mwe with a update query , thank you for the help any way